# Standalone player enter key is considered a character (Linux)

Tags: game-engine

What happens in the 'in-Blender' player:
[image: gif1]

What happens in the 'Standalone' player:
[image: gif2]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: you use Blender 2.79b game engine ?, why you dont try with UpBGE or Ketsji ? work much better they are forks of Blender Game Engine. they have more development in the game engine